# How do I display split ArrayList into 2 different columns?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, text-files, jtextarea

This is too display the text.

```
A = jTextArea2.getText();
B = jTextArea3.getText();  

Display = A+"              " + B + "         ";    
PrintWriter pwFile = null;

fc = new JFileChooser();    
int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(NewJFrame.this);

if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    String extension = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath() + ".txt";
    File file = new File(extension);

    try {
         pwFile = new PrintWriter(file);
         pwFile.write(Receipt()+Display);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Save successful", "Reminder", 1);
         pwFile.flush();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
```

This how it suppose to display 
How do I display split ArrayList into 2 different columns?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done this way:

```
List<String> teamA = Arrays.asList(
    "Virgil van Dijk", "Steven Gerrard", "Edilson Cavani", "Lionel Messi");
List<String> teamB = Arrays.asList(
    "Paul Pogba","Neymar Jr","Roberto Firmino","Fernando Torres", "Cristiano Ronaldo");

File teamFile = new File("teams.txt");

try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(teamFile))) {
    for (int i = 0, n = Math.max(teamA.size(), teamB.size()); i < n; i++) {
        String line = String.format("%-20s\t%-20s",
                        i < teamA.size() ? teamA.get(i) : "",
                        i < teamB.size() ? teamB.get(i) : "");
        writer.write(line.stripTrailing()));
        writer.write("\n");
    }
    writer.flush();
}
```

File output (players only):

```
Virgil van Dijk         Paul Pogba
Steven Gerrard          Neymar Jr
Edilson Cavani          Roberto Firmino
Lionel Messi            Fernando Torres
                        Cristiano Ronaldo
```

Comment: I have already store the array list and make it display in text area.Now i want to display the words in team A and team B to be displayed in text file.

Comment: This how i made the string displayed in textArea, how do i use this string with ur methods above

 
for(int i=0;i<lists[0].size();i++){
        jTextArea2.append(lists[0].get(i).toString());
        jTextArea2.append("\n");
        
    }
    
     for(int i=0;i<lists[1].size();i++){
        jTextArea3.append(lists[1].get(i).toString());
        jTextArea3.append("\n");
        
    }

Comment: You should have posted this code along with your question.
If your `lists` is defined as an array of Lists of Strings: `List<String>[] lists;` you can just set `List<String> teamA = lists[0]; List<String> teamB = lists[1];`, instead of my test values, that's it.